# get average value of rows with select option

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am working start on a small company project of attendence, and now I am want add a form related employee performance record.
there are some rating area like punctuality,initive,team player and its perameter
like 1 for poor,2 for fair, 3 for good and....
so I make select drop down for every area, but at last a feature is average overall rating
so how can I manage them .how can get average of all value?

Comment: You mean how to calculate an average value from a number of form fields?

Comment: yaa, I want to get average of all select value of a employee. like its get 3 in punctual, 4 in team work,3 for initive so in last average score of this employee

Comment: $average = ($punctuality + $initative + $team_player)/3

Comment: In general, you would use JavaScript to get each field value, and to calculate an average.

Comment: its 10 select field, if he <10 means poor,20-30 good,first how I add all select option value?

Comment: if i do this performance in oops , then how i do?

Answer (score 1):

Average is computed as a sum of values divided by number of these values, e.g.: if you get ratings like 3, 3, 2, 5 then the average is `(3 + 3 + 2 + 5)/5` which is `2.6`.

Comment: +1 Even though your answer looks a little silly because of obviousness, it is the most sane answer up to now. I'm just not sure whether this is what the OP was after. :)

Comment: @Bazzz, are you able to write less silly answer to this question? Looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

So you only have to sum up the values and then divide through the amount of values - where is the problem?

*SELECT AVG(your_field) FROM your_table ?*

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have anything to do with mySQL really

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option value="1">$lt;10</option>
  <option value="2">20-30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I like this answer, it gave me headache just to try and understand what you mean and how it matches the question of calculating an average.